# CSS border-color HEX does not change

Tags: css

I have deleted border-color, and add named color "solid red, dotted blue" etecera in section border after 8px it works, but as a new parameter it does not work at all.

```
style='border:8px; border-color: #3498db;min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 400px; height:800px; data-position="60% center"'>
```

Could someone please help me, I am not sure why border color is not working.

Comment: try using this if i have got your question correct: `style='border:8px solid #3498db; min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 400px; height:800px; data-position="60% center"'>` if its not working please share your HTML element as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is because there you need to specify what type of border you want. If you do not put solid then browser would not know what you want. So, you need to type the type of border you want and then color. It is better and easy to do like this:

```
border: 8px solid #3498db;
```

If still not working then try using this code:

```
border: 8px solid #3498db !important;
```

because some time other css style may inherit your style.

Hpe you understood.

Comment: Good answer! Inline style already has high precedence, I wouldn't suggest `!important` from the start.

Comment: I know that inline style has high precendence but some time inline css are hard to manage and when there is large amount of html code then inline css will make html code too bad

Comment: I agree with you inline styles are harder to manage and lose the benefit of reuse. I made note because the example in question uses inline styles instead of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that will work

```
border: 8px;border-color: #4497ce;border-style: dashed;min-width: 400px;width: 100%;min-height: 400px;height:800px;data-position="60% center";
```

**The border-color property does not work if it is used alone. Use the border-style property to set the border first.**

So while using border-color always use border-style css property too.